# How to store a DataRow after removing it from a DataTable for further use?

Tags: c#, datatable

I'm trying to implement undo redo in my `DataGrid` which is bound to a `DataTable`.

```
DataTable table;
DataRow row;
public InsertRowCommand(DataTable dt, DataRow dr)
{
    table = dt;
    row = dr;
}

public void Execute(object param)
{
    bool redo = (bool)param;
    if (redo)
    {
        table.Rows.Add(row);  //RowNotInTable Exception

    }
    else
    {  
        table.Rows.Remove(row);
    }
}
```

After undo I should be able to add the same row back to the `DataTable` on redo. 
I know that a `DataRow` should always be associated with a `DataTable`. How should I store that information?

EDIT : After the suggestion posted I tried doing the following

```
DataTable table;
    DataTable tableRemoved = new DataTable();
    DataRow row;
    DataRow rowRemoved;
    public InsertRowCommand(DataTable dt, DataRow dr)
    {
        table = dt;
        row = dr;
        rowRemoved = dr;
    }

    public void Execute(object param)
    {
        bool redo = (bool)param;
        if (redo)
        {
            row = tableRemoved.Rows[0];
            tableRemoved.Rows.Clear();
            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        else
        {
            table.Rows.Remove(row);
            tableRemoved.Rows.Add(rowRemoved); //ArgumentException thrown
        }
    }
```

On undo, when I try to add the row to the new table, Argument Exception (This row already belongs to another table.) is thrown.

Edit : Using `tableRemoved.ImportRow(row)` worked.

Comment: add your removed row to a `Stack<DataRow>`. By the way, for undo functionality, have a look at the Memento pattern.

Comment: Unfortunately, adding it to a stack gives rise to the same problem. RowNotInTable Exception.

Comment: I'm still not sure why this is happening. Would be glad if someone explained.

Answer (score 2):

Add another `DataTable tableRemoved;` that has not any `DataRow`.

After removing each row in `table` add that row to this `tableRemoved`, then you have what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The instance is tied with the DataTable. ImportFunction() makes an actual copy of the row.

```
tableRemoved = table.Clone();
public void Execute(object param)
    {
        bool redo = (bool)param;
        if (redo)
        {
            //Yet to implement
        }
        else
        {
            tableRemoved.ImportRow(row);
            table.Rows.Remove(row);

        }
    }
```